# Regarding the port security violation mode protected, what action needs to be taken when a new device replaces an old device?

Tags: mac-address, port-security

If I turn on port security and configure a port with the following; the violation mode to protected, the ageing time to 10 minutes, maximum number of mac addresses to 1.

If in the future I replace the device on the switch port, if I wait 10 minutes will the switch begin to accept the new frames with a new mac address? Or do I have to shutdown and reenable the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protect —The PFC drops packets with unknown source addresses until you remove a sufficient number of secure MAC addresses to drop below the maximum value.

so answer is no you don't need shutdown and re-enable port, after 10 minutes mac address will age out from port protected and new mac address will be assigned in case of using sticky.

You can add to aging type {absolute | inactivity} 
For absolute aging, all the secure addresses on this port ago out exactly after the time (minutes) specified and are removed from the secure address list. For inactive aging, the secure addresses on this port ago out only if there is no data traffic from the secure source address for the specified time period.